# Why is nothing displayed when print("Hello World!") in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Why does nothing show up on the screen when I do

```
display.setDefault( "background", 0, 0, 1 )
print("Hello World!")
```

but it shows when I do

```
display.setDefault( "background", 0, 0, 1 )

local myText = display.newText( "Hello World!", 100, 200, native.systemFont, 16 )
      myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )

print(myText)
```

Comment: yes, this is the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Corona documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/global/print.html) explains what `print` does:

> Receives any number of arguments and prints their values to `stdout` in the Corona Simulator Console, Xcode, ADB, etc. `print()` is not intended for formatted output, but rather as a quick way to show a value, typically for debugging. For formatted output, use `string.format`.

This means that your second [example](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html#examples) works without the `print(myText)` statement.

Comment: using string.format still doesn't do the job. I'm lost

Comment: @Mr.E `print` nor `string.format` is used to draw text on the screen. You must create a new text object as shown in the [examples](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html#examples).